# Android Fragments: Fragment is randomly recreated 1 day later

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have interesting issue with my app for some time now. Unfortunately I personally cant simulate this behavior on any of my phones but there are some users who are affected by this.

The issue is that I have `Fragment` which can be started only by pressing button by user. And this fragment is removed from stack after user exits it.

`Fragment` is used to open `WebView` with payment gateway to handle transactions (paying by credit card for items).

What is happening to some users is that if they leave phone and app in background (screen is locked and they are not using phone at all), sometimes when phone wakes up, transaction from like 2 days ago is executed without their knowledge. It will just randomly start that Fragment which was used 2 days ago without any user interaction.

It seems like `Fragment` just popped without calling constructor with data out of nowhere. The only way how to start this fragment again is to push button "Buy Item" on specific screen. This screen is not even there when user unlocked that phone.

I cant simulate this behavior but its happening to some users and its annoying.

Anyone knows what can be a cause of this and how to prevent that?

Code:

```
startFragmentForResult(
   PurchaseFragment(provider, id, sum.first, sum.second, discountId,
                    validFrom = validFromDateIso, duration = duration),
   object : FragmentResult<Boolean>() {
          override fun onFragmentResult(result: Boolean) {
               App.log("PurchaseDis: BasketFragment - onFragmentResult - enable back")
               mainActivity?.onBackEnabled(true)
               removeThis{
                  App.log("FragmentTest - BasketFragment - onFragmentResult - after remove")
                  mainActivity?.refreshData()
               }
    }
  })
}
    
    
fun startFragmentForResult(f: BaseFragment, receiver: FragmentResult<*>, hidePrevFragment: Boolean = true){
                val isStarting = mainActivity?.isFragmentStarting?:false
                if (!isStarting) {
                    mainActivity?.isFragmentStarting = true
                    fragmentStarting = true
                    app.sysLog("startFragmentForResult ($debugTitle) -> (${f.debugTitle})")
                    mainActivity?.startFragmentForResult(f, receiver, hidePrevFragment = hidePrevFragment)
                }else if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) App.log("Prevent multiple fragment start")
            }
    
    private var fragmentResultReceivers = HashMap<BaseFragment, BaseFragment.FragmentResult<*>>()
    
        fun startFragmentForResult(f: BaseFragment, receiver: BaseFragment.FragmentResult<*>, hidePrevFragment: Boolean = true) {
            fragmentResultReceivers[f] = receiver
            startFragment(f, hidePrevFragment = hidePrevFragment)
        }
    
        fun startFragment(
                    f: BaseFragment,
                    allowGoBack: Boolean = true,
                    hidePrevFragment: Boolean = true) {
                App.log("MainActivity: startFragment: ${f.title}")
                app.sysLog("startFragment (${f.debugTitle})")
                App.log("FragmentArray: ${getFragments().size}")
                makeFragmnentTransaction { ft ->
                    ft.setCustomAnimations(f.animIn, R.animator.fade_out)
                    val tag = f.javaClass.simpleName
                    if (allowGoBack && (f.isModal || f.canGoBack)) {
                        if (hidePrevFragment){
                            // hide previous fragment
                            getTopFragment()?.let {
                                ft.hide(it)
                                it.onHide()
                            }
                        }
                        ft.add(R.id.content, f, tag)
                    } else {
                        fragmentResultReceivers.values.forEach { it.onFragmentResultCanceled() }
                        fragmentResultReceivers.clear()
                        ft.replace(R.id.content, f, tag)
                    }
                    ft.runOnCommit {
                        updateUI(f)
                    }
                }
            }
    
         private fun makeFragmnentTransaction(body: (FragmentTransaction) -> Unit) {
                with(supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()) {
                    body(this)
                    commitAllowingStateLoss()
                }
        }

fun removeFragment(f: BaseFragment, initDefaultTabIfEmpty: Boolean = true, onCommit: (() -> Unit)? = null) {
        app.sysLog("removeFragment (${f.debugTitle})")
        makeFragmnentTransaction { ft ->
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fade_in, f.animOut)
            ft.remove(f)
            val frgs = getFragments()
            val fI = frgs.indexOf(f)
            if (fI == frgs.lastIndex && fI > 0) {
                // show previous fragment again - only if removed fragment is last one
                val af = frgs[fI - 1]
                app.sysLog("onShowAgain (${af.debugTitle})")
                af.onShowAgain()
                ft.show(af)
            }
            ft.setReorderingAllowed(false)
            ft.runOnCommit {
                afterFragmentRemoval(f, initDefaultTabIfEmpty)
                onCommit?.invoke()
            }
        }
    }

private fun getFragments(): List<BaseFragment> {
        return ArrayList<BaseFragment>().apply {
            for (e in supportFragmentManager.fragments) {
                if (e is BaseFragment)
                    add(e)
            }
        }
    }

fun getTopFragment(): BaseFragment? = getFragments().lastOrNull()
```

Maybe worth mentioning. I have data which phones are causing this issue:

```
"deviceBrand": "samsung",
"deviceModel": "SM-G991B",
"systemSdkInt": 33,

"deviceBrand": "samsung",
"deviceModel": "SM-G990B",
"systemSdkInt": 33,

"deviceBrand": "samsung",
"deviceModel": "SM-G970F",
"systemSdkInt": 31,
```

All of those devices are Samsung and all of them are Android 11+

**UPDATE:**

I have new logs from user which is affected by it:

```
2023/01/13 15:11:59: Purchase successful 
2023/01/13 15:11:59: returnFragmentResult (Purchase) 
2023/01/13 15:11:59: removeFragment (Purchase) 
2023/01/13 15:11:59: onShowAgain (Basket) 
2023/01/13 15:11:59: removeFragment (Basket) 
2023/01/13 15:11:59: onShowAgain (Tickets) 
2023/01/13 15:11:59: FragmentManagerListener: onFragmentDestroyed: Purchase 
2023/01/13 15:11:59: FragmentManagerListener: onFragmentDetached: Purchase 
2023/01/13 15:12:00: FragmentManagerListener: onFragmentDestroyed: Basket 
2023/01/13 15:12:00: FragmentManagerListener: onFragmentDetached: Basket 
2023/01/14 18:38:59: App create 
2023/01/14 18:39:00: PurchaseFragment.onCreate, args=Bundle[{duration=0, tickets={"tickets":[{"ticket_id":5443,"qty":4}]}, org_id=1208, provider=52, valid_from=null, price=4.23, currency=€}] 
2023/01/14 18:39:00: Buy tickets: {"tickets":[{"ticket_id":5443,"qty":4}]} 
2023/01/14 18:39:00: proceedWithPreorderId: 9857788, transact: null 
2023/01/14 18:39:00: Wait for preorder... 
2023/01/14 18:39:08: Purchase successful
```

I added log to `supportFragmentManager` listener to log state of each fragment in app. And it seems like after successful purchase, fragments are successfully detached and destroyed in manager but 1 day later as user wakes up phone and app, `MainActivity` is recreated (`onCreate` is called "App create") and 1 second later constructor of fragment is randomly out of nowhere called by the system. Even Fragment Manager listener is not detecting that fragment.

Not sure what can be wrong here.

Worth to mention that I've added to MainActivity function to clear backstack every time MainActivity is recreated to remove any fragments hanging there (if there are some):

```
     override fun onCreate(si: Bundle?) {
            clearFragmentBackstack()
            isRecreated = si != null
            if (si == null){
                val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
                splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition{ !areDataLoaded }
            } else {
                App.log("MainActivity: SavedStateTest: onCreate: recreated")
                val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
                splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition{ false }
            }
    
            super.onCreate(si)
            ...
}

 private fun clearFragmentBackstack(){
        if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
            val first =supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(0)
            supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(first.id, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the onCreate fun in the MainActivity

Comment: Is there a reason you check on 'si' before the super 'onCreate' call? Normally you have to call it after and clear fragments after, to be sure everything is initialized correctly

Comment: checking si just to skip splash screen if activity is recreated. I just wanna show splash screen only first time as app is started. Sometimes splash screen bugged and it just popped every 10 minutes as I opened app even as data were loaded

Comment: But you clear the fragments before it too, Try to move that fun after the onCreate to be sure the fragment rendered if it exists.

Comment: will try it and will let you know if it worked

Comment: You cant test the behaviour by going to developer settings and checking the option "don't keep activities", so that the activity is recreated whenever you go out and then again open back the app from background. There is a good chance the activity and fragment will be recreated in such a way that transaction is triggered again.

Answer (score 2):

when the activity is recreated again, it's normal that the last fragment was in the activity to be recreated but in your situation, it's a payment fragment that shouldn't be started by itself.
so to prevent such scenario.
You can create another status fragment and after payment is done, remove payment fragment from the stack and navigate to the status fragment.
also as we do in our apps. when the user initiates a payment, we are saving user's click time in shared preferences (datastore recently) and before making the payment we are checking for the user's click time, and if it was more than 5 minutes ago, we are not proceeding with the payment.

Comment: I removed payment fragment from the stack and I had PaymentSuccessfulFragment with check after it. And it still 1hr later as app was recreated it opened randomly Payment fragment which was second fragment which was according to FragmentManager detached and destroyed.